# NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Filter (Objectify Upgrade)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, objectify

How can I upgrade from V3 to V4 (and ultimately 5).

Following the upgrade instructions, I get an error:

> Unable to find Objectify.gwt.xml on your classpath

Adding objectify-gwt-1.2.1.jar to my classpath solved that, but then I get the servlet filter error:

> NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Filter

Filters were working fine before, so I assume objectify-gwt is the cause. Do I have the wrong version? How can I resolve this?

This is using the com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher developer mode server

EDIT:  This is hell.  Adding the servlet-api jar to the bootclasspath of the Appengine Developer Server gave me an error that some appengine jar couldn't be found
. I changed and then re-added the AppEngine version in the project set up to make sure they were there but the error remained so I added the AppEngine libraries to the bootclaspath list instead of the client list (in the run configurations [for the Appengine Dev Server] classpath tab).  Now I have a:

> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.util.Logging.initializeLogging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was to create a new run configuration.

In the Eclipse Top Menu choose RUN --> Run Configurations --> Web Application --> New

Not sure if it was related to the order I had set, or what but it created a new config that ran straight away.

Answer (score 1):

When you solved the classpath error I think you've overwritten the previous classpath specified by dot.  You have to have the current path in the classpath (specified by dot) alongwith the path to any other external jar file that you are using.

Comment: That sounds like a Tomcat solution.  Anyway, I don't believe I've ever had "." in my AppEngine Developer Server classpath.

Comment: Are you using any IDE or just the command prompt and notepad?

Comment: Using Eclipse and running the AppEngine Dev server so I am setting the classpath via the "Run Configurations" tab in Eclipse.